# How to display text out of color figure and easy to read in visNetwork?

Tags: r, dictionary, networking, visnetwork

I'm getting a Network Map done using R with `visNetwork` library, but I hate that displayed legend has text inside the shape, so it's size is defined by how big the name is and I don't want it to be that way to avoid confusion. In library [documentation](http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/legend.html) they add shapes that display text outside, but you have to set it group by group with a `visGroups` piece (`shape = "triangle"`, for example) for each one of the groups and I want it set in a way where I can leave that code set without specifically knowing how many groups they will be, because it won't necesarilly be the same number every time.

Coding below is the one I'm using (way much bigger, made it simple by selecting only some colums & rows):

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)


twd2 <- structure(c(0.0854374047081175, 0.116200039661793, 0.0289142580616779, 
                    0.12768720590989, 0.273786051264039, 0, 0.000593902599973604, 
                    0, 0.00184397276348455, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.106048390315551, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0.0142648455772593, 0, 0.0197857551361577, 0.0290239379534046, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00197967638677129, 0, 0.000296951299986802, 
                    0, 0.0111915576381184, 0, 0.00111081782587656, 0.0276104933163398, 
                    0, 0, 0.00487220095904272, 0.0149921777316026, 0, 0, 8.79855703664599e-05, 
                    0.00674104365369398, 0, 0, 0.0330935726540847, 0, 0, 0.0362094142674287, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0.00172168238114983, 0.00232061941841538, 0.0248983709144504
), .Dim = c(4L, 15L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("water_treatment", 
                                               "waste_water", "utility_model", "water_inlet", "waste_water_treatment", 
                                               "treatment_system", "model_discloses", "utility_model_discloses", 
                                               "water_outlet", "water_treatment_system", "treatment_device", 
                                               "water_tank", "sludge_treatment", "reverse_osmosis", "raw_water")))
twd2_num_col <- ncol(twd2)
twd2_cor <- cor(twd2, method = "pearson")
twd2_cor[ abs(twd2_cor) <  0.75 ] <- 0
twd2_cor[ abs(twd2_cor) >  0.925 ] <- 0
diag(twd2_cor) <- 0
graph <- graph.adjacency(twd2_cor, weighted=TRUE, mode="lower")
E(graph)$edge.width  <- E(graph)$weight
V(graph)$group       <- apply(twd2, 2, which.max)  # Max topic prob for colors
V(graph)$betweenness <- betweenness(graph, v = V(graph), directed = F)
V(graph)$degree      <- degree(graph, v = V(graph))

# Fit data for visNetwork
nm_data <<- toVisNetworkData(graph)
nodes <<- as.data.frame(nm_data[[1]], stringsAsFactors = F)
nodes <<- nodes[nodes$degree != 0,]    # Bye topics that don't have a connection (degree = 0)
nodes$group <<- swap(nodes$group , 1:length(topic_names), topic_names) # Swap long real names
nodes$label <<- rep("")


# Plot
  # Graph
  set.seed(17);visNetwork(as.data.frame(nodes, stringsAsFactors = F), 
                          as.data.frame(nm_data[[2]], stringsAsFactors = F), 
                          main = "Relation between topics")  %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, selectedBy = "group") %>%
    visInteraction(dragNodes = FALSE) %>%
    visLegend(useGroups = TRUE, main = "Topic")  %>%
    visNodes(shape = "dot",label = NULL) %>%
    visIgraphLayout(randomSeed = 17)
```

Additionaly, [here](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/328) they make reference to what I said aboud selecting type of shapes, but they don't add any code and I can't figure out if there is a way to do it directly and apply it to all group options or any other choice I could have.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't reproduce the output. In fact my IDE was crashing at the `V(graph)$betweenness`, i think that was due to some logical errors on `diag(twd2_cor) <- 0` & not assigning the 0's properly because there are NAs in the `twd2_cor`. HOWEVER, take a look at this, https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/legend.html I think if you introduce icons, the labels pull outside.

Comment: But still that way, you gotta do it group by group. Got an idea about how to make them all at once? @UltaPitt

Comment: Can't say what you meant really, I have to have whole picture, but since your code could be big and not suitable for SO, why not give other interactive packages a go too? There are many other options besides `visNetwork`. Try `geomnet` or my personal fav `networkD3` which has `igraph` integrations too. This website has contains most well integrated packages with igraph https://kateto.net/network-visualization Good luck! You can do it Melania!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ledges <- data.frame(color = c("lightblue", "red"), 
 label = c("reverse", "depends"), arrows =c("to", "from"), 
 font.align = "top") 
 
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "A", color = "red") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "B", color = "lightblue") %>%
  visLegend(addNodes = lnodes, addEdges = ledges, useGroups = FALSE)
```

**font.align = "top"** must do the job

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors;
See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/visNetwork/versions/2.0.9/topics/visNodes
The location of the label depends on the chosen shape, for default elipse this will be inside the node." The types with the label inside of it are: ellipse, circle, database, box, text. The ones with the label outside of it are: image, circularImage, diamond, dot, star, triangle, triangleDown, square and icon."